# Why is html call to js function getting html can't find variable error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have js/jquery dialog that has an some html input buttons that allow the user to select a color.  The button when clicked should call the javascript function changeColor.  I have reduced the code to a minimal set, yet when clicking the one of the color buttons I get an html "Reference Error: can't find variable: changeColor" error.  Not sure what I am missing.

```
function changeColor(themeColor) {
    var a = 1;
}

$('#change-theme').on('click', function() {
    $('#theme').dialog({
        width: 500,
        resizable: false,
        show: 'slide',
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: [{
            text: "Save",
            tabIndex:-1,
            'class':'dialog3_buttons',
            click: function(event) {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                return true;
            }
        }, {
            text: "Cancel",
            tabIndex:-1,
            'class':'dialog3_buttons',
            click: function(event) {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                return false;
            }
        }]
    })
    .height("auto");

    $("#theme").dialog( "option", "title", "Theme Picker - click a color to preview" );
    $("#theme").html(
        "<input type='button' class='color-button white-btn' id='color-button' name='white' onclick='javascript:changeColor()' >" +
        "<input type='button' class='color-button black-btn' id='color-button' name='black' onclick='javascript:changeColor()' >"
        );
    $('#theme').dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: Why not simply use `onclick='changeColor()'`

Comment: The `javascript:` label is not needed unless the first script on the page is NOT JavaScript. You can remove it

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign the function to a globally available scope if you want to call it from html like you do in your example

Add this line to your code

```
window.changeColor = changeColor;
```

See this working example https://jsfiddle.net/09ghrhap/1/

Comment: Thank you so much!  I would never have thought of that as being the issue.  Most appreciated.

Comment: @Tim: You are welcome. I have updated the example a bit, if you want to take a look.

Comment: Just move the function outside the $(function/$(document).ready

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to place the function into the `<head></head>`